# remote server phpmyadmin asking username password

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In MySQL workbench what is username/password for connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983064/in-mysql-workbench-what-is-username-password-for-connection)

I have phpmyadmin running good on my localhost server with no username and password.

Then i uploaded fresh copy of phpmyadmin on remote server.

I uploaded all files within phpmyadmin.

Its now asking username and password. I didn't set any.

So how can i access it.

I was wondering to do something with config file, but on my remote server i have config.sample.inc2 file  with remaining files.

How can i access my mysql database.

Comment: I have no idea where or what kind of username/password you're being asked for, but it's a **really, really bad idea** to have phpMyAdmin (or any other SQL db tool) available *without* a required authentication.

Comment: i didn't put anyusername and password. its asking by default. anyhow what would be better way to upload mysql database to remote server?

Comment: It's probably asking for the username/password for the MySQL user on your server for your account (which will most likely be different than the one you used locally). Please, though, *reread* my initial comment. **DO NOT** make phpMyAdmin available online *without requiring a username/password* to access it. This is asking for someone to hack your server. You would be best contacting your server's administrator/support.

Comment: just putting the PHPmyAdmin files in the remote server will not help to access it. you must change the required parameters within the config.inc.php. and as @JaredFarrish told, you should not keep it open to web as this could allow intrusion on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this to login:

Username: `root`

Password: *none (leave empty)*